# Container DIV not wrapping vertically

Tags: css, html, word-wrap

I realized there are probably thousands of questions about this already, but I have browsed through many of them and have not come up with a satisfying solution. I would really appreciate it if someone could offer some insight into what I should do.
The URL is http://www.ouranthology.com (the index page) 
As you can see, the content completely over flows the white background. I have tried adding the float:right and clear:both to the appropriate sections to no avail. So the coding is now back at where it started, with lots of < P > tags creating white space.

Thank you!

Comment: So do you want all of the content to be in the white background? Do you want scroll bars within the `#content` element?

Comment: What is the question? Sorry I didnt unserstand what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the style

```
.post {
  position: absolute;
  top: 590px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Serif;
}
```

Absolute positioning take the block out of the flow so it's parents do not count it as a child for rendering. Changing this to position:relative will fix the problem in your question.

To go a little further, try your best not to use pixel positioning (top:590px;) you should be able to get the look you are after with just using the normal flow to position. This make your layout far more resilient to change.

Also your structure looks quite strange. I see

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="post-title"></div>
      <div class="post-author"></div>
      <div class="post-excerp"></div>

      <div class="post-title"></div>
      <div class="post-author"></div>
      <div class="post-excerp"></div>

      <div class="post-title"></div>
      <div class="post-author"></div>
      <div class="post-excerp"></div>
```

I would of expected

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="post-title"></div>
      <div class="post-author"></div>
      <div class="post-excerp"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="post">
      <div class="post-title"></div>
      <div class="post-author"></div>
      <div class="post-excerp"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="post">
      <div class="post-title"></div>
      <div class="post-author"></div>
      <div class="post-excerp"></div>
    </div>
```

or even

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <article class="post">
      <div class="post-title"></div>
      <div class="post-author"></div>
      <div class="post-excerp"></div>
    </article>

    <article class="post">
      <div class="post-title"></div>
      <div class="post-author"></div>
      <div class="post-excerp"></div>
    </article>

    <article class="post">
      <div class="post-title"></div>
      <div class="post-author"></div>
      <div class="post-excerp"></div>
    </article>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion of changing everything to relative. It worked excellently

Answer (score 0):

If you want the White background longer according to the post
Then try 
`Position:Relative` in `post` class.